# Windows Search / Shell API - System.ItemUrl data

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-shell, windows-search

When I use the Windows Search API, I get results including the Shell API System.ItemUrl.

Since the Search API includes

- files
- emails (mapi15)
- IE history
- etc.,

the ItemUrl can be of any of these (and more).  Is there a way to fetch the contents or data of the item? Of course, if it's a `file:...` URL, I can just parse it and open it manually.  But, for other types of URLs, I'd like to fetch the data.

Note that I do *not* just want to open it locally, I want to fetch the data behind it.  I'd also, if possible, like to get the preview or thumbnail, if available.